# Excel search character range

Tags: microsoft-excel, regex

Is it possible to use character classes (`[A-C]` or `[abc]`) instead of wildcards in the `SEARCH` function of excel?

I want to do something like the following:

```
=SEARCH("[AB]"; A1)
```

This should result in the position of the first A or B in the cell A1.

Comment: no it's not possible. There are add-ins which provide VBA functions with regex capability, or you can also write your own function.

Comment: [so] duplicate: [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22542834)

Answer (score 0):

For your specific example, you can use **MIN()**:

[image]